# Create function too draw line

Tags: c++, opencv

So I'm pretty new to C++ and OpenCV and I've met on a problem where I'm reusing the same piece of code over and over again. So I would like to make this into a function where I can just input my points and it would run this code per argument I enter

So my question is : How do i do this code below as a Function where a just can replace "myPoint" with my own argument. So I don't need too copy paste the code several times

```
Vec3b Rightcolor = matImg.at<Vec3b>(myPoint); //defines the color at current positions
while(myPoint.x != cols){
    myPoint.x = myPoint.x +1; //extend the arrow
    int blue = Rightcolor .val[0];
    int green = Rightcolor .val[1];
    int red = Rightcolor .val[2];
    Rightcolor = matImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(myPoint); 
    if(blue == 255 && green == 255 && red == 255){
        break; //color is white at current position
    }
}
//end of function

if (m_debug) { //this draws the line in the main file
    line(matImg, bottomPoint,myPoint,cvScalar(0,0,102), 1, 8); 
}
```

updated with my function which doesn't work , as it doesnt draw a line and the rest of my code below it  :

```
Point increase(Mat img ,Point myPoint , int cols)
{
    Vec3b rightLaneColor = img.at<Vec3b>(myPoint); 
    while(myPoint.x != cols){
        myPoint.x = myPoint.x +1; //extend the arrow
        int blue = rightLaneColor.val[0];
        int green = rightLaneColor.val[1];
        int red = rightLaneColor.val[2];
        rightLaneColor = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(myPoint); //checks for color at current position
        if(blue == 255 && green == 255 && red == 255){
            break; //color is white at current position
        }
    }
    return myPoint;
}

void LaneDetector::processImage() {
    Mat mat_img(m_image);  //IPL Is outdated 
    Mat gray;
    Mat canny; //Canny for detecting edges
    cvtColor(mat_img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY); 
    Canny( grayImg, cannyImg, 50, 170, 3); 
    cvtColor(canny, mat_img, CV_GRAY2BGR);      
    cannyImg.release();

    int rows = mat_img.rows;
    int cols = mat_img.cols;

    Point bottomPoint;  /*Rightbottom  Arrow Start*/   
    Point rightPoint;  /*Right Arrow End*/

    bottomPoint.x = cols/2; 
    bottomPoint.y = 350;

    rightPoint.x = bottomPoint.x;  
    rightPoint.y = bottomPoint.y;

    /*
    Vec3b rightLaneColor = mat_img.at<Vec3b>(rightPoint); //defines the color at current positions
    while(rightPoint.x != cols){
        rightPoint.x = rightPoint.x +1; //extend the arrow
        int blue = rightLaneColor.val[0];
        int green = rightLaneColor.val[1];
        int red = rightLaneColor.val[2];
        rightLaneColor = mat_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(rightPoint); //checks for color at current position
        if(blue == 255 && green == 255 && red == 255){
            break; //color is white at current position
        }
    }
    */

    increase(mat_img,rightPoint,cols);
    if (m_debug) {
        line(mat_img, bottomPoint,rightPoint,cvScalar(80,255,12), 1,  8); 
    }
    imshow("Lanedetection", mat_img);
    cvWaitKey(10);

    //Steering instructions from here
    SteeringData sd;
    // Create container for finally sending the data.
    Container c(Container::USER_DATA_1, sd);
    // Send container.
    getConference().send(c);
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is how exactly do I the first code as a function that I can call and only replace "myPoint" argument

Comment: So just put it in a function and replace `myPoint` with the parameter of the function. If you don't know how to do that, you might want to read a C++ book, or at least check this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Comment: [can it be](http://answers.opencv.org/question/56095/draw-lines-from-centroid-of-contour-at-given-angle-till-edge-of-contour/), you're looking for something like the [LineIterator](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/dc/dd2/classcv_1_1LineIterator.html#ac83a4c574ce6a50a78a52d7eee10371b) ?

Comment: @Lighthat I've tried that but then it doesnt draw the line I want

Comment: @berak Ill check it out :)